# error while running electron app main.ts with sqlite db connection

Tags: reactjs, sqlite, electron, sequelize.js, ipc

"pg-hstore" is imported by "pg-hstore?commonjs-external", but could not be resolved – treating it as an external dependency.
✓ 891 modules transformed.
dist-electron/main.js  2,899.97 kB │ gzip: 456.42 kB
built in 5124ms.
App threw an error during load
Error: Cannot find module 'pg-hstore'
Require stack:

- /home/chiran/Documents/JEWELLERY PROJECT/Nithyakala_Jewellery_Management_System/application/dist-electron/main.js
- /home/chiran/Documents/JEWELLERY PROJECT/Nithyakala_Jewellery_Management_System/application/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js
- at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15
  at Function._resolveFilename (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:117576)
  at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:929:27
  at Function._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13327)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1150:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
  at Object. (/home/chiran/Documents/JEWELLERY PROJECT/Nithyakala_Jewellery_Management_System/application/dist-electron/main.js:10:22)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:14)
  at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)
  A JavaScript error occurred in the main process
  Uncaught Exception:
  Error: Cannot find module 'pg-hstore'
  Require stack:
- /home/chiran/Documents/JEWELLERY PROJECT/Nithyakala_Jewellery_Management_System/application/dist-electron/main.js
- /home/chiran/Documents/JEWELLERY PROJECT/Nithyakala_Jewellery_Management_System/application/node_modules/electron/dist/resources/default_app.asar/main.js
- at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1084:15
  at Function._resolveFilename (node:electron/js2c/browser_init:2:117576)
  at node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:929:27
  at Function._load (node:electron/js2c/asar_bundle:2:13327)
  at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1150:19)
  at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:110:18)
  at Object. (/home/chiran/Documents/JEWELLERY PROJECT/Nithyakala_Jewellery_Management_System/application/dist-electron/main.js:10:22)
  at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1271:14)
  at Object..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1326:10)
  at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1126:32)

I'm trying to create sqlite db with sequelize umzug migrations by calling ipc event in main.js function createWindow(). then comes this errors .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you need to install the `pg-hstore` module.

```
npm install --save pg-hstore
```

Comment: but now its works after installing pg-hstore, thanks